# Make camera in webgl with vertex shader?

Tags: webgl

I have some idea, but I'm not sure about it, because I'm no guru in webgl.

In WebGL, there is no camera. If one want to simulate it, then he has to do operations with a lot of objects... to be precise, he must change position to hundreds of thousands of vertices. I didn't study Three.js or Babylon js that deep, so I have no clue, how do they work with cameras.

Since vertex shader can transform vertex positions and because we can pass `camera matrix` to vertex shader, does it make sence to let it make calculations, so GPU will do the hard work instead of CPU?

Comment: http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-cameras/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean : **Create the view Matrix in the vertex shader using some data like position and orientation** instead of **Create it from application and send the resulting matrix in the shader** ?

Actually the last is the case for solutions like THREE.js and a lot of others :
An object representing a camera can be manipulated from JavaScript. Then at draw, the view matrix is built from some position and orientation parameters, and sent to the active shader program.

Creating a view matrix is done in some steps :

- Create a Identity matrix (no transformation) ;
- Combine the matrix with each transformations to apply to the camera : translations and rotations ;
- Invert the matrix (this computation may be quite heavy).

To decide where (or when) the matrix should be computed depends on the idea that the view matrix does not change in the process of drawing only one image. In fact view matrix and projection matrix are meant to be modified between two images.

Don't forget that vertex shader is executed once for each vertex you send to the pipeline.
If you make the computation of the view matrix in the vertex shader, it will be  re-computed a thousand times per image.

So the computation of the view matrix should better stay in the application and sent to the shader program.

If you want to take benefit from performances of shaders in floating point arithmetics, you can think about using compute shaders (unfortunately not present in WebGL) or take into account some mechanics to read back data from shader programs in order to compute the matrix once, and send it at next draw calls.

Comment: "Create it from application and send the resulting matrix in the shader" that is what I mean.